# crosswalk html video not playing after update

Tags: android, html, video, intel-xdk, crosswalk-project

1: i had make app to play video from html crosswalk app using intel xdk 
my app was working well with intel xdk 2966

video is inside my project and below is code

```
<video width="80%" height="auto" controls="controls" id="myVideo">
                <source src="video/kitkatfinal2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
```

2: after intel update video does not plays now ,do i need to update

i can see some whitelist after update , what i need to do to make it work

Please help i can not figure out

Comment: why marked down if u can not help do not vote down

Comment: Hi @mour_jewels, it may be worth taking this question over to Intel's support forum. If the issue is related to a specific build of the XDK, then they'll likely be your best bet for support. Cheers! (You can find them here: [https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk))

Answer (score 0):

We think this should be fixed now.  According to https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk/topic/594411 :

"there was a problem with our build system that has been resolved."